Mostrar fecha de caducidad de un precio oferta en una single page
Estoy desarrollando una página de venta de cursos online con Tutor LMS, Woocommerce y Elementor Pro. Deseo colocar la fecha de caducidad del precio en oferta en el lugar que yo decida. Con la ayuda de este código puedo mostrar la fecha solo al lado del precio:
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_get_price_html',
  'custom_price_html',
  100, 2
);

function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {
  $sales_price_from = get_post_meta( 
    $product->id,
    '_sale_price_dates_from',
    true
  );
  $sales_price_to   = get_post_meta(
    $product->id,
    '_sale_price_dates_to',
    true
  );

  if (
    is_single()
    && $product->is_on_sale()
    && $sales_price_to != "" 
  ) {
    $sales_price_date_from = date( "j M y", $sales_price_from );
    $sales_price_date_to   = date( "j M y", $sales_price_to );
    $price = str_replace( 
      '</ins>',
      ' </ins> <b>(Offer from ' . $sales_price_date_from
      . ' till ' . $sales_price_date_to . ')</b>',
      $price
    );
  }
  return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}

Alguna idea de como obtener extraer los meta field
_sale_price_dates_to // _sale_price_dates_from

De manera que se puedan colocar en cualquier parte de la página, ¿Quizá un php que active un shortcode?

puedes hacerlo creando un shortcode , por ejemplo '[print_sale_price_dates]', luego en functions.php o en el código de un plugin agregas la lógica del shortcode con add_shortcode(), algo así:
add_shortcode( 'print_sale_price_dates', function () {

global $product;

$sales_price = $product->get_sale_price();
$sales_price_date_from = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price_dates_from', true );
$sales_price_date_to   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price_dates_to', true );

$sales_price_output = str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> <b>(Offer from ' . $sales_price_date_from . ' till ' . $sales_price_date_to . ')</b>', $sales_price );

echo $sales_price_output; });

y ese shortcode lo puedes usar en cualquier página de producto.

Hola @og.lopar711, gracias por tomarte un tiempo en responder. Ya coloqué el códgio que me sugieres en mi tema hijo usando code snipet (php). Me he dirigido a la plantilla que estoy creando (página individual) y puse el shortcode [print_sale_price_dates] sin embargo no lo capta, entendería que podría ser poque este código es solo para página de productos, ¿es así?. Yo necesito ponerlo en una plantilla que estoy desarrollando usando Elementor y Tutor LMS.
